# Blinking fixed navigation in iOS Safari

Tags: css, mobile, css-position

So straight to the point:

I have a long page with a lot of content and a fixed navigation bar. The problem is that as i scroll down the navbar keeps blinking or disappearing for a split second. This is the CSS:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
      position: fixed;
      top:0
      left: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
      height: 50px;
      background: #333;
      z-index:3;
}
```

The problem is only in Safari, I tried Opera Mini and Chrome and it's fine.

Comment: Which version?  Support for `position: fixed` is relatively new for iOS.

Comment: It's iOS 6.1.2, not sure what version safari is.

Answer (score 1):

Add this declaration to the fixed element to force GPU acceleration:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```